# Without delay, how to hide all images in body with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a browser extension with js and jquery that hides all images (all img elements + background images of any element) and also put an option to show the image optionally if user wants right on the images.

So far I've tried to hide all matched elements in body with these:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').find("*").each(function() {
        imageHider($(this)); // my custom function
        bgImageHider($(this)); // also this is customized
    });
});
```

But some images aren't hidden because those didn't finish loading. So I did:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('body').find("*").each(function() {
        imageHider($(this));
        bgImageHider($(this));
    });
});
```

But this causes images to show up for some moments. How can I do this without any delay, meaning without images displayed for some moments?

Is it possible to trigger functions both `onready` and `onload` events?

Comment: can you add `img { display:none; }` to your css somewhere?  also @mplungjan's suggestion might run quite a bit faster, you should be able to just do it on `.ready()` as all tags should be loaded by then even if the img src is not

Comment: Yep! But in my original code, I was writing some custom functions instead of just hiding it. So I didn't modify that here. :D Sorry.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you are doing this? What is your original requirement?

Comment: I modified my question. Sorry for the ambiguous question last time.

Comment: Are you aware that the images will still load, you will just hide them?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to `remove` those elements because I'm `replacing` those with new `div` element and a button inside that `div` to load the image if the user wants to see that particular image.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("img").hide()
```

makes more sense - put it in a script tag at the bottom before the `</body>`

Faster:

```
<style>img { display:none }</style>
```

If you want them to take up space, use

```
<style>img { visibility:hidden }</style>
```

If you are inside some function, you can do

```
if($(this).is("img")) $(this).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through the image node with pure javascript would be the fastest way because it doesn't depend on the full jquery object to be loaded before executing .

**Example :**

```
var imageTags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < imageTags.length; i++){

         imageTags[i].style.display  = 'none';
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: However if jquery is loaded in the head, it will wait for it to load before continuing

Comment: Correct , but with the runtime will be a very significant and noticeable difference verses calling $ everytime for jQuery . Every time $ is used , the interpreter is searching the jQuery object . Its much faster to remove jQuery from this function .

Comment: It is cached in the window object.

Comment: Yes , but that does not stop many other jQuery functions from firing before your function is executed . This could be prooven in the console by setting an anchor at any $ inside your function.

Comment: I had to use `imageTags[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';` so the content wouldn't reflow

Answer (score 0):

Add some css to hide all images.

```
body.hideimages img{
    display:none;
}
```

Now you can do `$('body').addClass('hideimages')`

I assume this to be more performant than modifying the DOM for each image, which is what I suppose `jQuery` will be doing.

Comment: .hide() will likely add display:none using CSS unless you add a speed

Comment: @mplungjan Oh! so there won't be much of a change in the hiding time. TY for that info :)

Answer (score 0):

### **EDIT:**

OP changed specifications.

You can do something like this. In the demo it is managed with click events but you can call a function or w/e you want to handle triggering back the image and backgrounds.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/khd5f7wg/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elements = $("*:not(img)"),
    images = $("img");

  $.each(elements, function() {
    if ($(this).css("background-image") != "none") {
      var $this = $(this);
      var bgImg = $this.css("background-image");

      $this
        .css("background-image", "none")
        .on("click", function() {
          $this.css("background-image", bgImg);
        });
    }
  });

  $.each(images, function() {
    var cover = $("<div>", {
      "class": "img-wrapper is-covered"
    });
    $(this).wrap(cover);
  });
  $(".img-wrapper").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this
      .removeClass("is-covered")
      .find("img").addClass("is-visible");
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  visibility: hidden !important;
  position: relative;
}
.is-visible {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
.img-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.is-covered::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url("http://fillmurray.com/50/50") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://fillmurray.com/50/50">
<img src="http://fillmurray.com/50/50">
<img src="http://fillmurray.com/50/50">
<img src="http://fillmurray.com/50/50">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

---

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

> But this causes images to show up for some moments. How can I do this
>   without any delay, meaning without images displayed for some moments?

The fastest and easiest way to get rid of every image in your body is using CSS.

---

### **CSS Method:**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/6mswmqub/)**

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<p>
  Example text.
</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
```

---

### **jQuery Method:**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/c024ffgo/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<p>
  Example text.
</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
```

---

### **Javascript Method:**

*(Wrap it in a script tag right before closing the body tag.)*

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/pgv32ozd/)**

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<p>
  Example text.
</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
```

Comment: Sorry I think I wrote this when you had like 2 lines in your original answer. I edited it with the new requirements though.

Comment: Ah. I see. I did not notice

Comment: @RicardoRuiz , thanks for your edition. I implemented something similiar already. However, the answer doesn't seem to solve the original problem in practical situations, that is - "some images aren't hidden because those didn't finish loading".